# Congratz David Reed on your MVPship!

Tags: discussion

Congratulations are in order from the community =)

Keep up the good work!

Comment: Congratulations David Reed, well deserved!

Comment: Congratulations on being MVP. And on your new job at Salesforce.org release engineering. Unfortunately Salesforce employees can't also be MVPs. At least officially anyway. Your contributions to the community are still greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

If you reload the page, you'll find I'm not there anymore: I work for Salesforce.org now (as of a couple of weeks ago), so I cannot also be an MVP. I greatly appreciate the honor regardless! The announcement was just a crossed wire.

Comment: So many MVPs end up at Salesforce, but I think this is the first time I've seen someone join Salesforce before being given the honour!

Comment: Congratulations David!

Comment: Congratulations David.

Comment: belated congrats - I remember watching your reputation point total grow like wildfire and thinking to myself - that David, he knows his stuff!

Answer (score 13):

And you actually managed it just *before* being elected a mod! Pretty sure that was viewed positively for me when I was a candidate. Congratulations and well deserved!